# Two issues with mppm and Geyer-Hardcore hybrid interaction

Tags: spatstat

I am trying to fit a Hybrid interaction model to a set of point patterns, which I want to process and inspect further, but I run into two distinct (?) issues:

First, I tried to let mppm choose the Hardcore cutoff distance for me:

```
data("demohyper")
res1 <- mppm(Points ~ 1, interaction = Hybrid(Geyer(r=.1, sat=3), Hardcore(NA)), data=demohyper)
```

... but I got the following error:

```
Error in crosspaircounts(U, X, r) : 
  is.numeric(r) && length(r) == 1 is not TRUE
```

Instead, I determined the Hardcore distance manually, and fitted the model on a Hyperframe:

```
# find minimum hardcore distance in data set
res1 <- lapply(demohyper$Points, FUN = function(x) ppm(x~1, interaction = Hybrid(Geyer(r=.1, sat=3), Hardcore(NA))) )
minhc <- min(sapply(res1, FUN = function(x) { x$interaction$par$HybridComponent2$par$hc }))
minhc # .01166023

# fit mppm model with hc < minhc
res3 <- mppm(Points ~ 1, interaction = Hybrid(Geyer(r=.1, sat=3), Hardcore(.01)), data=demohyper)
sub <- subfits(res3, verbose=T)
```

... but this time, `subfits` returns an error:

```
Extracting stuff...done.
Determining active interactions...done.
Computing implied coefficients...Interaction, done.
Fisher information...Error in check.nvector(w, nrow(x), things = "rows of x") : 
  The length of ‘w’ (=4257) should equal the number of rows of x (=4229)
In addition: Warning message:
In split.default(values, id) :
  data length is not a multiple of split variable
```

Does anyone know whether this is an expected behaviour, that has to do with my choice of parameters? Else, I would be grateful for any advice on how to get `subfits` to work with a Hybrid interaction process.

Many thanks!

Comment: What version of spatstat are you using? I cannot reproduce this error with the current version of spatstat. A bug similar to this was fixed in spatstat 1.61-0, released in september 2019.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, I just upgraded to version 1.63-3. The first approach works, but `summary(res1)` now returns an error on my machine: `Error in if (any(relevant)) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`. Also, `subfits(res3, verbose=T)` still returns a similar error: `Error in if (g == 1) 0 else 2 * r : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`

Comment: This is a bug. I think we have fixed it in the latest development version (spatstat 1.63-3.002) available from the github repository (https://github.com/spatstat/spatstat). Please try that.

Comment: I installed the development version, and `subfits(res3, verbose=T)` now works. (However, `summary(res1)` still returns the same error.) But this keeps me going for now. Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are bugs.

They are now all fixed (we believe) in the latest development version (`spatstat 1.63-3.004`) available from the github repository.